# Swift escaping block declaration

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code:

```
typealias queryCompletionBlock = (_ finished:Bool) -> Void

func queryForParams(@escaping completion:queryCompletionBlock)
```

But I get an error

```
Attribute can only be applied to types, not declarations
```

The problem is the function requires block to be escaping. How do I declare the above function with an escaping block?

Comment: `func queryForParams(completion: @escaping queryCompletionBlock)`

Comment: `queryCompletionBlock` is longer than `(_ finished: Bool) -> Void` lol, I'd recommend just using `(_ finished: Bool) -> Void` directly.

Comment: Also, type names should be `UpperCamelCase`

Comment: That's okay, but I need to store the block in a variable.

Comment: I made the same mistake, I put `@escaping` before the word `completion:` when it should have came after the word.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
func queryForParams(completion: @escaping queryCompletionBlock)
```

Answer (score 4):

try `func queryForParams(completion: @escaping queryCompletionBlock)`